# Electric potential definition last portion

Tags: electrostatics, equilibrium

The amount of work done in carrying a unit positive charge from infinity to a point in the field against field keeping electrostatic equilibrium. What does it mean "keeping electrostatic equilibrium"?

Comment: It means at every point there is no net force on the particle, i.e., the particle does not get accelerated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the phrase should be **quasi-static equilibrium**. This means that the particle moves so slowly that it does not gain any kinetic energy. At each point on its path the electrostatic force on the particle is balanced by an applied force from whatever is causing it to move. There is no resultant force, so the work done by the applied force equals the work stored in the electro-static field.